# How does an operator change an aircraft's maintenance program from high-interval to low-interval?

Tags: airline-operations, aircraft-maintenance, easa-regulations

I have question for [CAMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuing_Airworthiness_Management_Organization) operators. If you have a maintenance program that is high-interval and the aircraft operates in excess of the maximum permissible hours and cycles you must go to a low-interval maintenance program.

How do you do the bridge check from high-interval to low-interval if you find yourself overdue for a low-interval check when you make the switch?

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the specific EASA language mandating the switch from high to low?

Comment: It is from EMBRAER SMRD:
[link](http://shrani.si/f/18/3X/Bud3Y0M/smrd.png)

Comment: That looks like it mandates a switch from low to high, not from high to low. I'm not as familiar with EASA, but it seems to me that you can always have a more stringent program than the minimum required. I'm sure someone else here will be able to give you a more practical answer.

Comment: Yes because I showed the low utilization SMRD not for high utilization. But it doesn't matter! it may also apply the other way from low to high. How do you change intervals to have proper remaining, beacuse the interval may be shorter or longer. Example: you have in high interval that you have 50% remaining, but when you go to low interval you are overdue, because the interval is shorter.

Comment: Ah, understand now. I've suggested some clarifying edits based on the comments; please roll back if they don't capture your meaning.